# sql server error - Lock Request Timeout exceeded

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging, locking

I get an error 'lock request time out exceeded' when a select query is run.

I know when this error will come. Some transaction should be locking the table.

But I need to know how to find that.

Please note that I cannot check it live when it is getting locked. It is like it happened in the past but I need to know what was the other transaction/query that was blocking it that time.

Simply put I want these events to be logged in sql error logs when this happens so that I can see later and find who was the long running query blocking it.

Any idea how to get it logged.
I tried to set the trace flags and check.
DBCC TRACEON (1204,1222,-1) 
But I couldn't find anything logged related to this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What version of sql server are you running on? If you are on a version prior to SQL 2008 then you will need to work with our IT people to analyse it in live as it happens.

If 2008 you can retrospectively view dead lock events as they are exposed in management views. Its stored as XML but you can break it out easily enough...

```
Select 
    DLEvent.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as DeadlockGraph
From
    (
        select CAST(target_data as xml) as DLData
        from sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
        join sys.dm_xe_sessions s 
        on s.address = st.event_session_address
        where name = 'system_health'
    ) AS DLData

CROSS APPLY DLData.nodes ('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS DLEvent (XEvent)

Where DLEvent.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') = 'xml_deadlock_report'
```

Comment: yeah I'm on sql 2008. Thanks for this query. But looks like it gives the details of deadlock events.
I'm not having deadlock I just get a lock time out. I mean the table is locked by some other long running transaction or query so my query times out. I just need a way to find who is the other query that is holding the lock. I cannot get to find it during the lock so I just want this events to be logged or saved somewhere for me to check.. 
I'm not in need of deadlock event, I want the lock time out events to be logged.

Comment: OK, second take and i am not in the office anymore so can't write a script this time. There is another sys.dm_tran_locks - but im fairly certain its live rather than historic. Activity monitor is the friendly face to this Click on the activity monitor icon in the toolbar in SSMS.  Finally profiler can be used for this sort of work and will keep track; just can't remember the options that are required - will look again in the morning.